# define a symbol local inside the function?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Just as an example, `put` inside the function create `x` property and its value globally:

```
(defun foo ()
  (put 'spam 'x 1))

(foo)

(get 'spam 'x) ; -> 1
```

Is it there way to set the symbol property locally?

Comment: What do you mean by locally - local to a function, to a buffer...?

Comment: I'm guessing you want `puthash`/`gethash`

Comment: @user4815162342 I intended for local to a function, but curious of local to a buffer too.

Comment: Scoping applies to variables, not to symbols.  But Emacs only provides symbol properties, not variable properties.  So, no, there is no such thing as "local" symbol properties.  OTOH, I'm pretty sure we can do what you need, if you tell us for what you wanted to use local properties.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you really want/need.  Sounds like this might be a case of [the X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/231821).  Maybe describe what you are really trying to do, instead of asking how-to-implement-this-solution for what you think might be an appropriate solution.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

No, because `'spam` is always the same symbol a property can't be set on it locally.

I don't know if this would be appropriate for your situation, but you could create a fresh symbol and put the property on that. Because the symbol wouldn't be available outside the function neither would the property.

```
(defun foo ()
  (let ((private (make-symbol "private")))
    (put private 'x 1)
    (get private 'x)))

(foo) ;=> 1

(get 'private 'x) ;=> nil
```

`make-symbol` returns a "newly allocated [and] uninterned symbol", which means the symbol returned by `(make-symbol "private")` is a different symbol from the global `'private` and all others. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html) for the Emacs manual's section on creating and interning symbols for more information.

Emacs also supports [buffer-local variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html), though that's not quite the same thing (the symbol's value is local to a particular buffer, but the symbol itself and its properties are still global).

If you just need to bind a value to a name locally, you could also use either Emacs 24's support for [lexical binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html) or, if you're on an older version, `lexical-let` from the `cl` package (which is included with Emacs).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it "locally" in the sense of dynamic-scoping:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(defun foo ()
  (cl-letf (((get 'spam 'x) 1))
    (get 'spam 'x)))

(foo) ; -> 1

(get 'spam 'x) ; -> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't quite understand what is that you want to do, seems to me that you are looking for a closure, that is, a function with an environment. To do so you have to enable lexical binding, which is supported starting from emacs 24.3 IIRC. To enable it set the buffer local variable lexical-binding to t. The popular example of a closure would be an adder factory, that is a function that returns a function that adds by a constant.

```
(defun make-adder (constant)
  (lambda (y) (+ y constant)))

(make-adder 3)
;; As you can see a closure is a function with an environment associated
=> (closure ((constant . 3) t) (y) (+ y constant))

(funcall (make-adder 3) 2)
=> 5
(funcall (make-adder 5) 2)
=> 8
```

So yes, using closures you can have private variables for a function.

Comment: No, this question is about symbol *properties* (which are distinct from their values as a variable).

Comment: Interesting I wasn't aware of them, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: See `C-h i g (elisp) Symbol Properties` for details.